# Pulsador con javascript (distintas funciones al presionar un boton por x segundos)

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando hacer un script que al pulsar sobre un boton ejecute funcion, pero al pulsar durante mas tiempo el mismo boton ejecute otra funcion... Alguien podria ayudarme? No se como hacerle y no encontre nada por internet de este tipo de cosas... Se que no es una pregunta bien formulada, pero no se me ocurre ni una minima parte de codigo de como podria ser, ayuda so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar los eventos `mouseDown` y `mouseUp` y dentro de estos eventos medir el tiempo transcurrido, de esta forma sabras cuanto tiempo paso desde que presiono y solto el click.

```js
var start;
var end;
var elapse;
var sTimeout;

function mouseDown() {
  start = Date.now();
  
  sTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Tu logica despues de los 2 segundos");
  }, 2000);
  
  document.getElementById("myMsg").style.color = "red";
}

function mouseUp() {
  end = Date.now();
  elapse = end - start
  document.getElementById("myMsg").style.color = "green";
  document.getElementById("myTime").innerText = "Tiempo transcurrido " + elapse;
  
  if(elapse < 2000){
    clearTimeout(sTimeout);
    console.log("Si solo realizo un click normal");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="myButton" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">
button
</button>

<p id="myMsg">Bienvendo a StackOverflow</p>
<p id="myTime"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Si necesitas utilizar tiempos de alta precisión puede utilizar [performance.now()](https://www.todojs.com/tiempo-de-alta-precision-en-javascript/)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: Crack, una pregunta... estoy intentando adaptar el codigo a lo que necesito... la cosa es que al hacer click sin mantener presionado, haga una accion, pero cuando supere los 2 segundos (2000ms) haga otra, intente con:
     if(start >= 2000){ var x = "superaste los 2 segundos";} else { var x = "";}  pero no me esta funcionando correctamente... alguna idea?

Comment: Actualize la respuesta, y recuerda que no es start es elapse. elapse es la que contiene la diferencia de tiempo. y start siempre la inicializas en el mouseDown

Comment: Ya... Pero lo que ando necesitando no es el elapse, es que cuando el click supere los 2 segundos, no haga falta soltar el click, solo al llegar a 2000ms haga la segunda function "colocas el resto de tu logica"

Comment: @Patrick e actualizado la pregunta. Espero te funcione.

Comment: Muchiisimas gracias crack!! Me ayudaste muchisimo!

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer uso de los dos eventos que componen un evento `click`, `mousedown` y el mouseup, con el fin de medir el tiempo de ejecución con el **performance API** y poder determinar la acción a realizar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Presioname</button>
    <script defer>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const button = document.querySelector('button')

            let initialTime = null
            let finalTime = null
            let resultTime = null

            button.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
                initialTime = performance.now()
            })
            button.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                finalTime = performance.now()
                resultTime = finalTime - initialTime

                if (resultTime < 1000) {
                    // Hacer algo cuando sea menos de un segundo
                }   else {
                    // Hacer algo cuando sea mas de un segundo
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!